# How to find the particular solution using method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the ODE
$$
x' = \begin{bmatrix}
      2 & -1 & 0\\
      0 & 2 & 1\\
      0 & 0 & 2
     \end{bmatrix}x
   + \begin{bmatrix}
      e^{-4t}\\
      3t\\
      -e^{-4t}
     \end{bmatrix},
$$

I know we can write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{-4t}\\
 3t\\
 -e^{-4t}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\
 0\\
 -1
\end{bmatrix} e^{-4t} 
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\
 3\\
 0
\end{bmatrix}t.
$$
Then I'm stuck on guessing the form of the particular solution.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The initial stimulation vector $\begin{bmatrix}
                       e^{-4t}\\
                       3t\\
                       -e^{-4t}
                      \end{bmatrix}$ is fortunately well-shaped and contains elements like $p(x)\exp(-kx)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$ and real value $k$. I strongly suggest you to consider the same form (i.e. $p(x)\exp(-kx)$) for the particular solution, replace it in the equation and get the final response.

Comment: I try to guess the form like a*e^-4t+b*t+c, where a,b, and c are some matrices. But I'm not sure if it's the right form

Comment: It is not incorrect and may suffice, but if it didn't, try to include more terms. Something like $(at^2+bt+c)\exp(-4t)+dt^2+et+f$ ($a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constants).

Comment: @nasser you shoud post your answer will upvote it for sure

Comment: @user577215664 it actually takes me lots of time because I use dmath environment in latex which mathjax does not support here, so I have to convert the latex again to make it show here OK. It is ok. will try to do that some other time. I am tired now.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much! It's explained so well! Really appreciate your work!

Comment: Related: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/3%3A_Systems_of_ODEs/3.7%3A_Multiple_Eigenvalues

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to compute the eigenvalues of your matrix.

$$
|A - \lambda I|=
\begin{vmatrix}
2- \lambda & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2- \lambda & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2- \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix} = 
(2-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
2- \lambda & -1 \\
0 & 2- \lambda \\
\end{vmatrix} =
(2-\lambda)^3=0
$$
This implies that:
$$
\lambda_{1,2,3} = 2 
$$
of multiplicity $3$.

To find the eigenvectors, we compute
$$
A-2I=
\begin{bmatrix}
2- 2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2- 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2- 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From the observation above, $A$ is a defective matrix. So, we will have to apply the Jordan normal form to find a suitable basis. After computing $A-2I$, we can choose our eigenvectors to take the standard basis, ie:
$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The solution to the differential equation of the form $\dot{x}=Ax+bv$ with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0 $is given by
$$
x=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-\tau)}bvd\tau
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence, the solution to the equation above is of the form:
$$
x=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{t-t_0} && (t-t_0)e^{t-t_0} && \frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2}e^{t-t_0}\\
0 && e^{t-t_0} && (t-t_0)e^{t-t_0} \\
0 && 0 && e^{t-t_0} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} \\
c_{2} \\
c_{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
+\int_{t_0}^t 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2(t-\tau)} & (t- \tau)e^{2(t-\tau)} & \frac{(t- \tau)^2}{2}e^{2(t-\tau)}\\
0 & e^{2(t-\tau)} & (t- \tau)e^{2(t-\tau)} \\
0 & 0 & e^{2(t-\tau)} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-4\tau} \\
3\tau \\
-e^{-4\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau
$$
$$
= c_1e^{t-t_0}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} +
c_2e^{t-t_0}
\begin{bmatrix}
t-t_0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} +
c_3e^{t-t_0}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2} \\
t-t_0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+\int_{t_0}^t 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2(t-\tau)} & (t- \tau)e^{2(t-\tau)} & \frac{(t- \tau)^2}{2}e^{2(t-\tau)}\\
0 & e^{2(t-\tau)} & (t- \tau)e^{2(t-\tau)} \\
0 & 0 & e^{2(t-\tau)} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-4\tau} \\
3\tau \\
-e^{-4\tau} \\
\end{bmatrix} d\tau
$$

for $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, and assuming initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$ consisting of entries $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$.

Comment: In the solution, how did you come up with the $e^{2t}$, $t\,e^{2t}$ and $\frac{t^2}{2} e^{2t}$ factors?

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd eigenvector are not correct since $$\left(\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}-2\,{\bf I}\right)\begin{bmatrix}0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

The problem only has one eigenvector, and thus modal analysis cannot be used.

Comment: Since $A$ is a defective matrix, we have to represent it in the Jordan normal form. By observation of $(A-2I)$, we can observe that we can use the standard basis to represent as the basis vectors. Another observation can be seen as $A$ is already represented in a form of a Jordan block.

Taking basis vectors $v_1 = (1,0,0)^T, v_2=(0,1,0)^T$ and $v_3=(0,0,1)^T$, we can show that:
$$ Av_1 = 2v_1, Av_2 = -v_1 + 2v_2, Av_3 = v_2 + 2v_3$$.

Hence, the ODE will take the basis of $e^{2t}, te^{2t}, \frac{t^2}{2}e^{2t}$ as the eigenvalues are of multiplicity $3$.

Comment: I read more about this and you are right.